# Fill up array with missing elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:

```
array:6 [▼
    0 => 2
    1 => 2
    2 => 2
    6 => 5
    10 => 3
    11 => 1
]
```

I would like to check for a range of numbers e.g. 0 to 11 if these keys exist in my array. If not I want to create the element with the missing key and give it the value 0.

So I would end up with an array like this:

```
array:6 [▼
   0 => 2
   1 => 2
   2 => 2
   3 => 0
   4 => 0
   5 => 0
   6 => 5
   7 => 0
   8 => 0
   9 => 0
   10 => 3
   11 => 1
]
```

I tried something like this:

```
$range = range(0,11);

foreach($myArray as $key => $value){
  if(!in_array($key, $range)){
    $myArray[$key] = 0;
  }
}
```

But I just get the same array as at the beginning of the question.

Comment: And where are you stuck at doing this?

Comment: Do you need to fill the missing `array keys` to with `value 0`??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an array with [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) and pass it the amount of keys you want with [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) and fill the array with 0's. After that you can replace all elements which you already have in your array with [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php).

```
<?php

    $array = [2 => 3, 5 => 2, 11 => 7];

    $result = array_replace(array_fill_keys(range(0, 11), 0), $array);
    print_r($result);

?>
```

---

The problem with your code is that you only loop over the elements of your array. So if you have just 3 elements you will just loop over these 3 elements.

If you want to fix your current code you would have to loop over the `$range` and then check if the key, not the value, exists in your array and if yes use the value from it otherwise create the element with the value 0.

Fixed code:

```
$range = range(0,11);
$result = [];

foreach($range as $key){
    if(isset($array[$key]))
        $result[$key] = $array[$key];
    else
        $result[$key] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code if you have range of array key upto 11 only.

```
for($i=0; $i<=11;$i++){
    if(!array_key_exists($i,$array)){
      $array[$i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `max(array_keys($array))` instead `11` it will find max key in the array; and you don't need to check last item (`11`) because it always will be exists.

Comment: Using your method it will append all 0 keys at end.

Comment: try if(!isset($array[$i])) instead of if(!array_key_exists($i,$array))

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

1) Using `key()` we find last key number.

2) Using `array_key_exists(key,array)` check for key exist in array or not.

3) Fill it in new array.

```
$arr = array(
    0 => 2,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 2,
    6 => 5,
    10 => 3,
    11 => 1,
   );
end($arr);
$endKey = key($arr);

for($i=0;$i<$endKey;$i++)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($i, $arr))
    {
        $newarr[$i] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $newarr[$i] = $arr[$i];
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 3
)
```

Comment: why minus vote?. Its working i have checked and tested. @Marco

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `array_diff_key` and `array_fill` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$diff = array_diff_key(array_fill(0,12,0), $arr);
$result = $arr + $diff;
ksort($result);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to browse the whole array for set missing keys value 0. I make a function for doing this, Check if the index is missing then set 0.

```
$array = array('0' => 2, '1' => 2, '2' => 2, '6' => 5, '10' => 3, '11' => 1);
function cleanArray(&$array){
    end($array);
    $max = key($array); //Get the final key as max!
    for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
        if(!isset($array[$i])){
            $array[$i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

cleanArray($array);
ksort($array);
print_r($array);
```